# Subjective discounting factor in the utility function

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics

Consider the following utility function in an infinite time-horizon set up:

\begin{equation}
U= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(\rho-n)t}u(c(t)) dt
\end{equation}

Why we assume that $\rho >n$, where $\rho $ is the pure rate of time preferences and $n$ is the population growth rate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before going streight to your question, let me stress an important point.
The utility function you have written is the utility function for all family members of the household. Indeed, you are implicitily assuming that the household size  $L(t)=L(0)e^{nt}$ follows this normalization $L(0)\equiv1$. Eventually, $L(t)=e^{nt}$.

Then, $\rho -n$ is the effective discount rate because the household derives utility from the consumption per capita of its additional members in the future as well.

Clearly, you need to add a discounting term otherwise the utility function might get an infinite value (not an interesting case to analyze).

Finally, $\rho -n >0$ ensures finite discounted utility. Take the limit of the discounting term and see what happens for $\rho -n <0$